Is it possible to get the exact script invocation in Python?
I would like my python script to produce a text file containing the exact command line the user entered to invoke the script. In the past, I have done the following in bash:
echo "$0" "$@" > "${output_dir}/configuration/invocation.txt"
Is there something equivalent in python? As noted here, "the command line arguments are already handled by the shell before they are sent into sys.argv. Therefore, shell quoting and whitespace are gone and cannot be exactly reconstructed."

The same thing is true for a bash script, the arguments are processed by the original shell before they're put into $@.

You can use shlex.quote() to add the necessary quotes when writing to a file. These won't be the same as the original invocation, but that shouldn't matter.

shlex.quote won't reproduce shell-replaced arguments like environment variables or the result of subshells ($(cmd)).

The exact invocation? No. If getting the quoting correct is all you care about in order to reproduce a run then that's a different question.

I'm okay with something equivalent to the exact invocation. It sounds like shlex is a viable option.

@Woodford As I said in my first comment, the shell has already replaced those. shlex.quote() will be like their echo command.

The suggestions in the comments to use shlex are proving sufficient for my needs.
